# Spring PermissionEvaluator multiple permissions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have created a customPermissionEvaluator and I'm trying to find the best way of using hasPermission implementation for multiple permissions. 
I know that If I use the next way:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#foo, 'test1') and hasPermission(#foo2, 'test2')")
```

it will call

```
@Override   
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2);
```

twice, I want to avoid hasPermission invoked more then one time.

any ideas???
thanks.

Comment: did you get a way to do that?

Comment: yes, I'm writing the permissions in the @PreAuthorize with a JSON array structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is writing all the needed permissions in the @PreAuthorize with a JSON array structure.

For example:
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#foo, '[ "test1", "test2", "test3" ]')")

Comment: Can you provide the sample example?

Comment: added an example

Answer (score 1):

You can give names to your components use them in annotation

Example:

PermissionEvaluator:

```
@Component("userPermissionEvaluator")
public class RegistrationPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
  
  @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
   // your code

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
 // your code
        return false;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @PreAuthorize("@userPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission(#id, 'user', 'read')")
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

and if there was another implementation with a different name of the component

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {

    @PreAuthorize("@productPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission(#id, 'product', 'read')")
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> getProductById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

and so you can do several implementations with different names